# AS3 - Finding a Sub-string thats inbetween two other sub strings

Tags: actionscript-3, substring

I'm creating a flash application, which loads a file from a server, and stores it in a string. I'm wanting to find the substring within that string, which is inbetween two known substrings.

Note. I don't want to do this with reg-ex as i'd like it to be easily reusable.

Ideally I'd like a function which i can re-use, by passing the beginning and ending substrings.

e.g. something along these lines..

```
function getSubString(start:String, end:String):String
```

I'm struggling on this one. If anyone can help it'd be much appreciated. Thank you.

*No doubt this is one of those questions that gets the answer "Why didn't you just google it..". I have done, and didn't find much! Sorry!*

**Edit:** There may be more than one instance of the 'start' and 'end' substrings within the string, i'm wanting it between the first instance of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getSubString(start:String, end:String, fullString:String):String {
    var startIndex:Number = fullString.indexOf(start) + start.length;
    var endIndex:Number = fullString.indexOf(end) - 1;// You can change this to 
                                                      // lastIndexOf in order to
                                                      // get the string between the 
                                                      //first instance of start and
                                                      // the last index of end
    return fullString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}
```

I haven't tested it so you may find an off by 1 error.

Comment: you might want to change var endIndex:Number to fullString.indexOf(end,startIndex)  to make sure you don't get an endIndex which is lower than the startIndex.